# Webpack sourcemaps are inaccurate using either Babel 6 or Babel 7

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, source-maps

**I've tried far too many configurations to list out here.**

I have tried everything I have seen suggested on the web from parsing it  through UglifyJS to upgrading to the beta of Babel 7. I've tried every Webpack `devtool` setting and only had success with the ones that spit out evaluated code, which of course is not very helpful.

**Here's a demonstration of the issue:** http://recordit.co/rHKX3quofA

Sourcemaps come out 100% perfectly in ParcelJS (which I can't use for other reasons unfortunately), but in Webpack, line numbers are consistently off and variables seem to show inaccurate values when inspected.

It's gotten to the point that it's seriously detrimental to my ability to continue my project, and I cannot find any solution.

**I've read that the comments added to the bottom of the files produced by Webpack interfere with Chrome/Electron's ability to map properly**, but I can't find any way to disable these to try that fix besides an undocumented plugin several years old.

Sourcemaps produced for production use seem to have no issue at all, but the same settings for development yield disappointment.

Has anyone found a way to fix this? Thanks very much.

Comment: I had similar problems and found this - https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/issues/175#issuecomment-347257392

Comment: Thanks @olore. Unfortunately it isn't a Chrome issue in my case, and actually the uglifyjs sourcemaps seem to work fine, but I can only get uglifyjs to work for production, not during development where I do 99% of my debugging.